# TFS Import work item types. How to set filename argument from url

Tags: xml, tfs, tfs-workitem

One of the arguments to run the importwitd command from command line is:

**/f: FileName**: The path and file name of the XML definition file that contains the types of work items to be exported or imported. If you omit this parameter when you use the exportwitd command, the XML appears in the Command Prompt window.

What I want to do is to set the file as an url, like: "https://mysvn.com:443/tfstemplates/task.xml"

Usually, I run it as:

```
witadmin importwitd /collection:http://server:82/tfs/DefaultCollection /f:"c:\tfstemplates\Task.xml" /p:"PROJECT NAME"
```

What I want to do is to run it as:

```
witadmin importwitd /collection:http://server:82/tfs/DefaultCollection /f:"https://mysvn:443/tfstemplates/task.xml" /p:"PROJECT NAME"
```

But when I do that, I got this error message: "**The given path's format is not supported.**"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use a URL in that parameter. To do what you want you would need to Get the file locally first and then import it from the temp local location.